# How can I use cin and cout at same time without interrupt?

Tags: c++, time, cout, cin

I'm writing a win32 console application, who has two thread, one keep using `cout` to write something to console, and the other keep using `cin` to try get some input. Both works well, I haven't got lose of data, except that it's not beautiful...Sometimes while I'm entering something the other thread `cout` something out and those two things hold together. **Is there anyway I can get them seperate?** If there's noway to do it I have to open a window and redirect the `cout` stream to it, which I really don't want to do...

Comment: You could redirect `cout` to a file?

Comment: no, I need to show it in realtime...

Comment: you should use a library for terminal control.  
I can point you to PDCurses http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/ but I've never used it, so I cannot help you more than this

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are receiving the input character by character. Then whenever you need to output something start by moving the output cursor the the start of the current line with a carriage return '\r'

Then make sure your output overwrites the current input by padding it with spaces if necessary.

Finally print a line feed to start a new line and rewrite your current input

```
std::cout << "\r" << output << padding << "\n" << currentinput;
```